# Deserialize malformed JSON with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a snippet of JSON that looks like this:

```
{"123":{"name":"test","info":"abc"}}
```

**The `123` is an ID and can change on each request. This is beyond my control.**

I want to Deserialize the JSON using JSON.NET. I have tried:

```
 User u = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
```

However, this does not work unless I define the `JsonProperty` attribute like so:

```
[JsonProperty("123")]
public string ID { get; set; }
```

But of course I cannot actually do this because the ID `123` will change on every request.

How can I read the ID property using JSON.NET and apply it to the ID class?

Comment: It would work with a `KeyValuePair<string, object>`. You could try deserializing it in a temporary `object` buffer and then map it to your `User` instance.

Comment: It's not malformed; just awkwardly formed. Basically it's a KVP of <int, User> where user has properties 'name' and 'info'

Comment: I thought , In your class structure must be defined first class RootObject . In class Rootobject , u have to declare all json attribute as get set method.

Comment: As pointed out, `KeyValuePair<string, object>` does not work. Using a `Dictionary` instead, as per @YuvalItzchakov's answer, will do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var json = "{\"123\":{\"name\":\"test\",\"info\":\"abc\"}}";

var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, User>>(json);
var user = rootObject.Select(kvp => new User 
                                    { ID = kvp.Key, 
                                      Name = kvp.Value.Name, 
                                      Info = kvp.Value.Info 
                                    }).First();
```

This does have some unnecessary overhead, but considering the circumstances, it would do.

Comment: Agreed but works - thank you.

Comment: This solution is actually beautifull! Worked perfectly for me, even when the Value part is an array of objects!

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it this way:

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

var myObject = result as JObject;
var properties = myObject.Properties();
var property = properties.FirstOrDefault(); // take first element 
string name = property.Name;

foreach (var item in properties)
{
    var jProperty = item as JProperty;
    var nestedJson = jProperty.Value.ToString();
    dynamic nestedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(nestedJson); // or put it into a model/data structure
}
```

Comment: Thanks - interesting but tricky to get at the actual user data now.

Comment: i know... but you can deserialize the nested object also... updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about having JSON formed as follows (if at all changing JSON schema is allowed):

```
{
    "ID": "123",
    "Properties":{"name":"test","info":"abc"}
}
```

This way it must be possible.

Comment: Sorry not allowed - I did bold it in the question ;-)